# Exercise: Understanding the definition of prime ends

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

currently I am reading Christian Pommerenke's book about boundary Behavoir of Conformal maps () in chapter $2.4$ he denotes the notion of an prime end that is given by the following:

For now denote by $G$ some domain in $\mathbb C_{\infty}$, then he first defines

**Def**: (Null-chains) We call a sequence of sets null-chains of $G$ if

1. $C_n$ is a crosscut of $G$ for all $n \geq 0$ (where a crosscut is a jordan arc containing two (not necessarly distinct points) $a$ and $b$.
2. $\overline{C_n} \cap \overline{C_{n+1}} = \emptyset$ for $n \geq 0$
3. $C_n$ seperates $C_0$ and $C_{n+1}$ for $n \geq 1$
4. The spherical diamter $d_{\infty} (C_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Examples are given by the following: [image]

Note that by topological arguments on can show that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ there is exactly one component of $V_n$ of $G - C_n$ that does not contain $C_0$ and the sequence of $(V_n)$ is decreasing. He now defines Prime Ends the following way

**Def: Prime Ends**: We call two null chains $(C_n)$ and $(C^{\prime}_n)$ of $G$, equivalent if for sufficently large $m$, there exists $n$ such that
$$
C^{\prime}_m \text{ seperates } C_n \text{ from } C_0, \quad C_m \text{ separates } C^{\prime}_n \text{ from } C^{\prime}_0.
$$

**Here comes the exercise**:

Let $E$ be a perfect set (i.e. compact and without isolated points) on $\mathbb T$ that contains no arc. Show that
$$
G = \mathbb D \setminus ( r \zeta : \frac{1}{2} \leq r < 1, \zeta \in E ),
$$
has uncountable many prime arcs. Secondly if $p$ is a prime arc show that $I(p) = \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} \overline{V_n}$ is a continuum.

**What I have tried so far**:

**How do the prime arcs "look like": Here I am a bit confused I imagine the chains for one $p \in P(G)$ (set of prime ends) to look like half arcs similiar to the second chain in the left picture, however this runs into the problem that the impression $V(p) = \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} \overline{V}_n$ is only one point not a continuum, and this is where I a stuck.

**Uncountable Many**: If the set of prime arcs is non-empty then it is easy to see that is uncountable basically consider $P(G) = \cup_{p \in P(G)} \{p\}$ as the set of prime arcs of $G$ then since $E$ is perfect, I believe by baire catory it should be easy to proof that $P(G)$ of first baire category, hence cannot be the union countable nowwhere dense sets, but each of the prime ends is exactly that, thus $P(G)$ is uncountable.